# How to pass a Function defined in a String to an Event of Widget in Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart, parameters

I want to define a function in a String (in the database) and put it on the OnChanged() of a widget in Flutter.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30205826/9798865 Let me know if this work

Comment: I can't make it work, but in the same question I saw an answer that it is not possible. Thank you @HBock!

Comment: No, it is not possible.  You would need to map `String`s to `Function`s yourself.

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin, yes but I wanted to define the functions outside the code... I will solve it another way